# Handle xml data in an activerecord pattern way: Any way?

Tags: c#, xml, activerecord

I would like to handle xml data in an activerecord way, so 1 class for each xml structure (I will need an xsd obviusly) and the possibility to do operations like *Users.FindAll()* like castle activerecord do.

The problem is, obviusly, that those are xml file, not relational databases.

Are there any library to achieve this? If is MS library and not a third party library is better, obviusly.

To understand why I would like to achieve this, I'll explain the program I'm building so you can eventually give me some suggestions if a different approach is better:

The program "output" will be something like a long MS-Word (or pdf) document which will contains information about **how** a company handles the privacy of their customers, following the local legislation.

I will have, so, a "global" xml file which contains something like Jobs (as defined in law, but law can change so should be editable by the user) that each employee can have in it's company (there will be other data too, this is a generic example).

Then, I will have an xml file for each company the user would like to use this program for. This xml file will have a list of employees where each emplyee have a reference to the Job (chosen from the global xml file).

Obviusly the program will have much more data, but this explains how it works.

I'm still not sure if I must use a relational databse, what really frighten me in case I use one, is that I will have "troubles" in allowing the user to export/import data if he install the program on a new computer. Also I would like to avoid to force the user to install a database on his computer (well, an sqlite-like database could be ok because is on a file).

Any suggestion about this?
Thanks to everyone

Comment: Definitely not, and I'm sorry for this but they slow down my browser, however I used wordreference 5 times while I was writing this question... I really tried it but english is definitely not my native language. I know how to express as I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Linq-to-XML is pretty easy to use, there are many more things to do when it comes to reading and storing related data in a way a RDBMS does. An RDBMS is all about referential integrity, ACID transactions, concurrent users, performance enhancements, to name a few elements that spring to my mind now. Thinking of this daunting task, I think doing this all by yourself is more scary than deploying a database file.

There are some [XML-based databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database), but I don't know how mature and user friendly they are. I even remember having read of database systems based on plain text files.

I would go for the paved roads and use a relational database, possibly a [local database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341.aspx), as you already suggested. Lots of support and tooling available.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)?

Comment: I read about it, however it helps only in *reading*; I don't have any improvement about *writing*. Infact I have to create all those instances to effectively insert a new user. I would like to do something like *new User("name",ThatJob).Save();* or at least something easier than writing all that code for each class
Any library out there that help in inserting data? (where I read about the code to insert data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.add.aspx )

Comment: You can easily write data to file with Linq To Xml. XElement contains methods for this purposes. You can write something like this 
new User("name","role").Save(XDocument doc).

Comment: Mhh..., can you post a sample? I mean, do I have to write .Save by my own (so that serialize the class correctly) or is it already implemented? I would like to avoid writing the tedious part of *xmlWriter.Write("Bla",mybla);* for each property I have in the class like for xmlserializer, is quite boring

Comment: Container is some proxy class that wraps xml api.
var container=new Container("D:\\users.xml");
new User("name","role").Save(container);
And the save method will look like this:

var userNode = new XElement("User");
                    userNode.SetAttributeValue("name",name);
                    userNode.SetAttributeValue("role", role);
                    container.Document.Root.Element("Users").Add(userNode);
                    container.CommitChanges();

Comment: It's interesting, however I'll still look around because it doesn't satisfact me (sorry it's mine problem, nothing against your answer). I would like something that doesn't need that I implement those methods (they must be built in, like castle activerecord)

Comment: I understood what you want. I think that there is no better API for XML than Linq To XML for .NET Framework. Try to search but i don't think you'll find something better.